# Orthonormal sequences in Hilbert spaces.

Tags: hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

I am having some confusion with some topics that have to do with orthogonality. I am a bit new to these ideas and thought I had them understood but I realize I do not.

Suppose we have a Hilbert space $H$, then is it always true we can construct an orthonormal sequence in $H$? Note I don't mean a basis, but simply just an orthonormal sequence in $H$. If so, how do we construct this? Do we just start with a unit vector then find another vector that is orthogonal to the first, and continue this process recursively? Does it matter if $H$ is finite or infinite dimensional?

Comment: Yes: if $H$ is infinite dimensional, you can always choose some vector orthogonal to all previous chosen vectors. Of course if $H$ is finite dimensional, then you have to stop at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use something similar to the [Gram-Schmidt orthonormalization process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) : consider a Hilbert space $\mathcal H$, if $\dim \mathcal H < \infty$, then we can find a finite orthonormal sequence of length $\dim \mathcal H$. If $\dim \mathcal H = \infty$, we can find an infinite orthonormal sequence.

*Convention* : I take the physicist's convention that the hermitian product $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is anti-linear in the first variable and linear in the second one.

- If $\mathcal H \neq 0$, then there is $x\in\mathcal H$ with $x\neq 0$. We let $x_1 = x/\|x\|$ and we have the first term of our orthonormal sequence.
- Assume we have built a finite orthonormal sequence $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$. If $\mathcal H = \operatorname{Span}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, then we have an orthonormal basis, and there are no larger orthonormal sequences. Else, there is $y\in \mathcal H \backslash \operatorname{Span}(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$. Then, let :
  $$x = y - \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i,y)x_i$$
  We have $x\neq 0$ and $(x_i,x) = 0$ for all $i\in \{1,\ldots,n\}$. Then let $x_{n+1} = x/\|x\|$, and $(x_1,\ldots,x_n,x_{n+1})$ is an orthonormal sequence.

If $\mathcal H$ is finite dimensional, this process goes on until $n = \dim\mathcal H$. If $\mathcal H$ is infinite dimensional, it goes on forever.

Comment: Thank you so much for the comprehensive answer!